# Xamarin.Forms add 4 digit password when starting or resumng on the app

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have Xamarin.Forms App. I want to add a pin and when user opens the app he must enter the pin he added. First user needs to log in to the app. My question is where to save the pin and how to make enter the pin on every start or appear in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Obvious answer here is a Databse, Something like SQL would work.

As for The start of the application 
[App Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application?view=xamarin-forms)

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }

 protected override void OnStart()
 {
    // Handle when your app starts
 }

 protected override void OnSleep()
 {
    // Handle when your app sleeps
 }

 protected override void OnResume()
 {
    // Handle when your app resumes
 }

}
```

You can use the OnStart() Method in your App Class and possibly run a Popup Using something like
[Rg.Plugins.Popups](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)

Or On your MainPage(Landing Page) You can Initialise a Popup That locks the application essentially until a pin is Entered

You could Also Check if its the users first login if not Navigate them to a "Pin" View, And Hide all navigation, Let them Enter the pin you check it against the way you decided on and if you find the pin you navigate them back to the Home Page

Now back to Where to store this, If you want to save it on the Device
A Option like [Xamarin Essential's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android)  or Even Application.Current.Properties(Essential's is my favourite  here)

> Xamarin.Essentials provides a single cross-platform API that works with any iOS, Android, or UWP application that can be accessed from shared code no matter how the user interface is created. See the platform & feature support guide for more information on supported operating systems.

If you need to login on the first open. Again you can save something to Preferences or Properties

Something like:

```
bool firstOpen = true;
 Preferences.Set("firstOpen", firstOpen);
```

To be honest you dont even need to worry what you set in here, Because you can just check if it contains the Key "firstOpen"

```
var getPref = context.getSharedPreferences("firstOpen", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if(getPref.contains("firstOpen"){
//Do Something
}
```

At the end of the day It depends, You have Options look into everything a little bit and decide which scenario works better for you.

Have a look at Preference's its a simple, Save's Everything as a string, With Key's and value's you use [Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/)  to save and deserialize to Load Here's a [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to)

Comment: When user make an acccount must Add Pin. I saved it in the database . When he log  in i save the pin in the device

Comment: i will check your solution